# How to stop Serilog from trimming long messages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I'm logging long JSON text to console for debugging purpose but Serilog is trimming part of it. How to stop Serilog from trimming long messages?

Serilog is configured as below in an aspnet core 2.2 application.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Debug(outputTemplate:
                    "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate:
                    "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}")
                .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: How long is the "long JSON text"?

Comment: @Raj Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?